# How to get String array from String with unknown punctuation/ word dividers?

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I get random Strings as input and all I want is to get the ENGLISH words for keyword search app apart from the punctuation marks ([see punctuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punctuation)) or word dividers ( say, white space, multi-white spaces ). This issue is that I won't know the basis for spiting the Strings. For example, if I get a String "FLORENCE - FIRE/TOMORROW", I would like to get String array as {"FLORENCE", "FIRE", "TOMORROW" }. Besides, sometimes it also happen that a single word will come, say, "MELBOURNE" and just need to get the array as {"MELBOURNE"}. Capital letters has nothing to do with the question.

How can I do this ?

Comment: if your using java you should look into either the `string.split()` method or the `stringTokenizer` class

Answer (score 1):

```
"FLORENCE - FIRE/TOMORROW".split("\\s+-\\s+|/")
```

use split `or` with your delimiters.

Comment: Thanks , but, I need solution for all cases. This was just an example.